# How to return a zip file from S3 in API response Python 3.6.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I am new with python was trying to build an API that would mimic how AWS presigned urls would work. I have created a custom url that hits our endpoint and after resolving the url it should return the data associated to that url. The data is a zip file present on S3. I tried using aiboto3 to get the data

```
 async with aioboto3.client("s3", config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'), aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,) as s3_client:
        try:
            s3_ob = await s3_client.get_object(Bucket=DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME, Key=path)
```

however this step fails as it gives a

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 12: invalid continuation byte
```

which is understandable as zip might not be utf-8 encoded.
Hence, I moved on to use boto3 and simply get the object data like this

```
s3_file = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME, Key=path)
response = s3_file["Body"].read()
```

response is a byte array with data like

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x10\x08...
```

How do I return this data from the API if I want that at the user's end it should automatically download this zip file if this url is hit in the browser? Right now it does get downloaded since I have set the following, but I'm unable to open it as it says unsupported format.

(Set this so that it triggers download automatically)

```
request.response.content_type = 'binary/octet-stream'
            request.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET'
            request.response.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'X-filename'
            request.response.headers['X-filename'] = path
            request.response.content_disposition = 'attachment;filename=hello.zip'
```

This API is being written in Frontdoor(API gateway). The function returning this data is an async function. This code works fine for a csv file and I simply return response.decode('utf-8'), however I can't do the same in this case since decoding it gives an error. I tried using `latin1` as the decoding for the zip file data however it messes with the data and the downloaded file says format not supported.

Comment: Are you using any python framework to serve that api ?

Comment: @MahendraSinghMeena we're using pyramid framework

Comment: You may use FileResponse (https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.FileResponse), for that you need to save the file somewhere on the pyramid server and then it will be returned to the client that is using your api.